# Simple way to track mouse coordinates while moving over HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there a simple way to get relative mouse coordinates while moving mouse over HTML5 canvas?

I found this:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
    // get canvas position
    var obj = canvas;
    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;
    while (obj && obj.tagName != 'BODY') {
        top += obj.offsetTop;
        left += obj.offsetLeft;
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }

    // return relative mouse position
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - left + window.pageXOffset;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - top + window.pageYOffset;
    return {
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
    };
}
```

But it seems too heavy to me. Is there a reason using frameworks (like Kinetic) when working with canvas to simplify such things?

Comment: What's heavy about the code you posted?

Comment: Kinetic.js has mouse movement tracking. Perhaps you could use that library already implemented?

Comment: In my opinion this code is extremelly heavy. Imagine, if in order to retrive such parameters as mouse coordinates or key code you have to do such manipulations!

It's like assembly language in comparison with high-level one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using your `mousemove` on your canvas use this:

```
$(function () { 
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.onmousemove = mousePos;
 });

function mousePos(e) {
    if (e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if (e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could position canvas absolutely and then remove while loop.

Ultimately, if canvas would not move, you could cache it's offset and then use cached value.

And to cover all cases: if canvas would have `fixed` position, you'll need not consider scrolling: `pageXOffset`, `pageYOffset`.